# assing button.click dynamically using lambda

Tags: c#

So i wanna create several buttons dynamically and define their click event, since i'm doing it inside 2 for's and i need the button and the 2 variables that control the for i can't call a function to handle the even click therefore im using the lambda expression (=>) to do it.

this is part of the code:

```
        Button retangulo;
        for (int i = 0; i < Jogo.tamanho; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Jogo.tamanho; j++)
            {
                 retangulo = new Button()
                {
                    Name = "rectangle" + (i * Jogo.tamanho + j),
                    BackColor = Color.LightGray,
                    Location = new Point(9 + (j * 43), 20 + (i * 43)),
                    Size = new Size(40, 40),
                    FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup,
                };
                retangulo.Click += (obj,e) =>
                {
                    if (Jogo.tabuleiro[i, j].Bomba) retangulo.Image = Resources.download;
                    Jogo.tabuleiro[i, j].Numero = Jogo.Surroundings(Jogo.tabuleiro[i, j]);
                };
                groupBox2.Controls.Add(retangulo);
            }
        }
```

Problem:

the i and j are always the same, i intend for them to change according to the respective button position on the array.
my guess is that the code save into the click event is jogo.tabuleiro[i][j] instead of the jogo.tabuleiro[0][0] for instance.

Comment: Might want to fix that title.

Comment: You need to create local copies of i and j inside the inner for block.

Comment: tried that , didn't work
just to be clear what u sugesting is:

retangulo.Click += (obj,e) =>
                {
                    int n=i;
                    // and then replace the i inside the inner block for the n
                    ...
                }